# "so they are" or "so are they"

Tags: grammar

Which way is correct:

> Just as questions with no answers are highly attractive to you,
>   so they are to your competitors too.

or:

> Just as questions with no answers are highly attractive to you,
>   so are they to your competitors too.

The more I look at these sentences the more I'm confused ;-) Please help.

Comment: No confusion. Both are correct.

Comment: The first case can do with a comma after *so they are*.

Answer (score 1):

They're both mostly correct, but are really odd/awkward.  I would suggest something more like

> These questions appeal to your competitors just as much as they do to you.

Answer (score 0):

So are they means and they are also. So they are usually indicates surprise on the part of the speaker.

Examples:

She is English and so are they...

(Speaker 1) - They're not blue! They're green! 
(Speaker 2) - So they are!